# Angular ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I tryed simple layout but it seems nothing gets render. Layout.html is being loaded and that is all. There are no errors in console.
This is part of my config file

```
    $stateProvider
      .state('layout', {
         url: '',
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: viewsRoot + "layout.html",
          controller: 'LayoutController',

      })
      .state('layout.sidebar', {
         abstract: true,
          templateUrl: viewsRoot + "sidebar.html",
          controller: 'SidebarController'
      })
          .state('layout.mainview', {
              abstract: true,
              templateUrl: viewsRoot + "container.html",

          })
        .state('layout.mainview.object-details', {
            url: '/object-details',
            templateUrl: viewsRoot + "object-details.html",
            controller: 'ObjectDetailsController'
        })
       .state('layout.mainview.home', {
           url: '/',
           templateUrl: viewsRoot + "home.html",
           controller: 'HomeController'
       })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

This is layout.html:

```html
 <div  ui-view="sidebar">
</div>
<div class="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="page-content" style="min-height: 1227px">
       
        <!-- END PAGE SPINNER -->
        <div  ui-view="mainview">
        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE CONTENT-->
    </div>
</div>
```

This is container.html

```html
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

Should I use nested views instead of nested states?

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify what renders where.  You have two areas, "siderbar" and "mainview", but you are not identifying what template goes to what view in your state configs

```
$stateProvider
  .state('layout.home',{
    views: {
      'mainview': {
        templateUrl: '...',
        controller: ...
      },
      'siderbar': {
        templateUrl: '...',
        controller: ...
      }
    }
  })
```

See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views for more information

Comment: It seems does not help